# Hidden field validation

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

I have a hidden value in my form, but when I tried a security scan using HP WebInspect tool, its getting manipulated and shows vulnerability. I tried validating this hidden field but still this tool can manipulate the value. What to do for this?

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you could , encrypt the value and store in cookies or hidden feild

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if you're using the last version of HP WebInspect tool (from this point forward HPWT).

Marking a hidden field of one html form as a vulnerability and manipulate it's value cannot be called a good tool.

Check the settings page of HPWT. In the `Scan Settings / Method` there are options related with forms. Check the `autofill web forms` options for the forms, and if it don't works set the checkbox for `Prompt for web forms values during scan ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the manipulated data affect your code don't try to use this `$("#someId").text();`.

Hope it help.